# Como ocultar un b-tab con VueJS si no tiene texto

Tags: bootstrap, vue.js, textarea, bootstrap-vue, hide

La cuestión es que tengo un panel de pestañas hecho con `Bootstrap` de `Vue`. Cada una de estas pestañas tiene un `textarea` el cual muestra un texto. Básicamente no se cómo hacer para que aquella pestaña cuyo `textarea` esté vacio, no se muestre en el panel de pestañas.

Hasta ahora solo se me había ocurrido meter un `v-if` que comparase la longitud del `string` que contiene el `textarea` y si es menor de 1, que no se mostrara, pero desconozco la sintaxis para hacer eso. Si a alguien se le ocurre otra forma de hacerlo bienvenida sea.

Comment: ¿Con qué información se rellena el textarea? ¿Quieres ocultarlo y mostrarlo según cambie lo que haya puesto el usuario? Tendrás que enlazar el textarea con un dato (con un v-model) de vue y poner el v-if en la pestaña comprobando la longitud de ese dato

Comment: Si cada texto es un componente diferente puedes utilizar el método de carácter diferentes componentes viene en la documentación. Lo malo es que tienes que utilizar webpack o algún cli te pasaría código pero aún no me aprendo la sintaxis

Answer (score 0):

De un modo muy burdo pero creo que puede valer para que tengas una idea:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <div id="tab0" v-if="text0.length != 0">
    <textarea v-model="text0" />
  </div>
  <div id="tab1" v-if="text1.length != 0">
    <textarea v-model="text1" />
  </div>
  <div id="tab2" v-if="text2.length != 0">
    <textarea v-model="text2" />
  </div>
</div>
```